# Get result true if all the rows have met the condition in sql

Tags: sql

Basically i'm looking for solution for the condition, where table has the following rows and i want to select only those where condition is met by all the rows.

```
ID  category    flag
1       A       1
2       A       1
3       A       0
4       B       1
5       C       0
```

Expected Result is B where flag is true for its category.

Comment: Thank you Fahmi for the edit.

Comment: Also specify the expected result.

Comment: Thakyou all for your efforts.I think i need to post the question with actual table values so that i could get the desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the categories for which **the minimum flag is 1** (meaning there is **no** `flag = 0`):

```
select category
from tablename
group by category
having min(flag) = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kCqpTNTeBsU7EtHxWHtoE7/0).
Results:

```
| category |
| -------- |
| B        |
```

Comment: thanks but if we add another record of B with flag 0 it shows no result

Comment: Of course it does not show any result since there is a 0 for B. This is the requirement that you set in your question.

Comment: Actually what i'm looking is to get the category if all the rows of it has condition true.

Comment: Exactly. So if B has a row with 1(true) and a row with 0(false) then it will not be returned.

Answer (score 3):

I hope that my answer would be helpful to your problem. In the subquery, a list of the categories is created by filtering the flags.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename a 
WHERE a.category NOT IN (
      SELECT b.category
      FROM tablename  b 
      WHERE b.flag=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated subquery with `not exists`

```
select * from tablename a 
where not exists (select 1 from tablename b where a.category=b.cateogry and flag=0)
```

Comment: Thanks Fahmi but not solving the purpose.God bless

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct category,flag from test where category in
(select t.category from (select category,flag from test 
group by category,flag)t group by t.category having count(*)=1) 
and flag=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate table of categories, then `not exists` is often the fastest method:

```
select c.*
from categories c
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.category = c.category and 
                        t.flag = 0
                 );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(category, flag)`.  If you don't have such a table, then forpas's solution is quite effective.